# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, all parenthesis have been closed but still not working

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

I want to create two tables `Publisher` and `Book`. Here are the SQL statements for creating the tables.

I want to create a foreign key constraint in the Book table. I'm not sure why it's throwing this error. I cross-checked all the parenthesis. The syntax seems to be fine but it's not creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE Publisher
(
    pub_name varchar2(128) PRIMARY KEY, 
    phone integer, 
    address varchar2(20)
);


CREATE TABLE Book
(
    book_id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar2(256),
    pub_year number(4) UNSIGNED,
    pub_name REFERENCES Publisher(pub_name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Where [in the Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/index.html) did you find that `unsigned` is a valid modifier for `number`?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, there's no `UNSIGNED` nor `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Publisher(
  2  pub_name varchar2(128) PRIMARY KEY,
  3  phone    integer,
  4  address  varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE Book(
  2  book_id  integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  3  title    varchar2(256),
  4  pub_year number(4),
  5  pub_name REFERENCES Publisher(pub_name) ON DELETE CASCADE);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One error is the `on update cascade`.  However, this is a second error:

```
pub_year number(4) UNSIGNED,
```

Because `unsigned` isn't allowed here, you can use a constraint instead:

```
pub_year number(4) check (pub_year > 0),
```

That said, you probably want a more specific constraint, something like:

```
pub_year number(4) check (pub_year > 1950 and pub_year < 2100),
```

Note that this will represent the year as an integer (there is `scale` on the number definition so the default is `0`).  If you attempt to insert a number like 2020.20, then the value will be truncated -- rather than generating an error.